# Git - remove all stashes from the git stash list after a certain point

Tags: git, git-stash

I have the following stash list (`git stash list`):

```
stash@{0}: WIP on foobar: baz qux
stash@{1}: WIP on worble: norf 
stash@{2}: On blazbliz: finishes blah 
stash@{3}: WIP on foobar: baz qux in progress
stash@{4}: WIP on wizzle: wuzzle 
stash@{5}: On wiggle: wiggle 
stash@{6}: On blah: yada 
stash@{7}: WIP on hello: started hello world
```

How do I drop all stashes after a certain point? say for example all stashes after `stash@{2}` so that I end up with

```
stash@{0}: WIP on foobar: baz qux
stash@{1}: WIP on worble: norf 
stash@{2}: On blazbliz: finishes blah
```

Answer (score 5):

`git stash drop` is used to drop a stash.

`git stash drop` drops the top stash - or a stash reference which looks like: `stash@{n}` which `n` nominates which stash to drop.

Hence, `git stash drop stash@{1}` will remove the stash at place 1.

So, it's not possible to drop a list of stash.

Alternatively, all the stash are stored at `.git/logs/refs/stash`. Each line contains 1 stash in the reverse order in which they were created. (Latest will be at the top)

So, to drop multiple stash at once, open the file from your projects home dir, delete as many as you want and save it.

Comment: You can run this command to delete all stash at once : git stash clear